# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRGB' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm in the middle of following some beginning lessons on webgl on udacity.  In the online snippets they used `material.ambient` for MeshLambertMaterial.

Below, I'm attempting to create a basic cube example from scratch, but when I try to replace MeshBasicMaterial with MeshLambertMaterial I'm running into problems trying to get the cube to display.

Why isn't ambient defined on material, the way it is in the udacity tutorials?  The threejs docs aren't very helpful, they don't even mention an ambient method on material... did the API change?

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var kv = 0.4;

//this line gets error: app.js:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRGB' of undefined
material.ambient.setRGB(kv * material.color.r, kv * material.color.g, kv * material.color.b);

var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
}
render();
```

Comment: Did you try and debug it, to see what material.ambient contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

three.js materials no longer have an `ambient` property.

The *ambient reflectance of the material* (how the material responds to indirect, or ambient, light) is now assumed to be the same as the *diffuse reflectance of the material* (how the material responds to direct light).

The diffuse reflectance of the material is also known as the material's `color`.

three.js r.80

Comment: Thanks.  Is there anyway for those of us starting with older examples to learn about these deprecated methods and transition to newer apis?  I suppose reading the source code history...